# XSL Transformer does not select tag values with relative path

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm having an issue in selecting values of a XML from a XSL transformer. 
The XML that I'm transforming is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<message creationDateTime="2012-12-31T12:25:21Z" id="20121231122504.f555357c-bcc1-483d-93ea-29551a2dc52f" xmlns="urn:netdocs:schemas:message">
  <sender xmlns="">
    <id entityIdTypeCoded="GLN">5600000000427</id>
    <addressInformation>
      <countryCode>PT</countryCode>
    </addressInformation>
  </sender>
  <receiver xmlns="">
    <id entityIdTypeCoded="GLN">560000001XXXX</id>
    <addressInformation>
      <countryCode>PT</countryCode>
    </addressInformation>
  </receiver>
  <order documentNumber="000123285849" documentDate="2012-12-31" schemaVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:netdocs:schemas:document">  
    <seller xmlns="">
      <id entityIdTypeCoded="GLN">560000001XXXX</id>
      <name>TUDO BEM SA</name>
      <addressInformation>
        <address></address>
        <city></city>
        <postalCode>
          <zip></zip>
          <area></area>
        </postalCode>
        <countryCode>PT</countryCode>
      </addressInformation>
    </seller>
    <buyer xmlns="">
      <id entityIdTypeCoded="GLN">5600000022078</id>
      <name>ENT. ALV FARMACIA</name>
      <addressInformation>
        <address></address>
        <city></city>
        <postalCode>
          <zip></zip>
          <area></area>
        </postalCode>
        <countryCode>PT</countryCode>
      </addressInformation>
    </buyer>
    <billTo xmlns="">
      <id entityIdTypeCoded="GLN">5600000000403</id>
      <name>Modelo Continente Hipermercados, SA </name>
      <addressInformation>
        <address></address>
        <city></city>
        <postalCode>
          <zip></zip>
          <area></area>
        </postalCode>
        <countryCode>PT</countryCode>
      </addressInformation>
    </billTo>
    <shipTo xmlns="">
      <id entityIdTypeCoded="GLN">5600000022078</id>
      <name>ENT. ALV FARMACIA</name>
      <addressInformation>
        <address></address>
        <city></city>
        <postalCode>
          <zip></zip>
          <area></area>
        </postalCode>
        <countryCode>PT</countryCode>
      </addressInformation>
    </shipTo>
    <additionalDate type="DELIVERY" xmlns="">2013-01-03T10:30:00</additionalDate>
    <currencyCode xmlns="">EUR</currencyCode>
    <lineItem number="1" xmlns="">
      <gtinCode>0083800004XXX</gtinCode>
      <buyerItemCode>3798XXX</buyerItemCode>
      <description>PRODUTO XX 2X6L</description>
      <quantity>
        <value>80</value>
        <unitOfMeasure>EA</unitOfMeasure>
      </quantity>
      <netUnitPrice>0.00</netUnitPrice>
      <quantityOfPackages>
        <value>80</value>
        <packageType>BX</packageType>
        <quantityPerPackage>96</quantityPerPackage>
      </quantityOfPackages>
      <vatPercentage>23</vatPercentage>
      <netAmount>0</netAmount>
    </lineItem>
    <lineItem number="2" xmlns="">
      <gtinCode>0083800004XXX</gtinCode>
      <buyerItemCode>3798XXX</buyerItemCode>
      <description>PRODUTO XX 2X6ML</description>
      <quantity>
        <value>80</value>
        <unitOfMeasure>EA</unitOfMeasure>
      </quantity>
      <netUnitPrice>0.00</netUnitPrice>
      <quantityOfPackages>
        <value>10</value>
        <packageType>BX</packageType>
        <quantityPerPackage>96</quantityPerPackage>
      </quantityOfPackages>
      <vatPercentage>23</vatPercentage>
      <netAmount>0</netAmount>
    </lineItem>
  </order>
</message>
```

I'm trying to take the value for //order/additionalDate and the value of attribute documentNumber of order tag. I've tried using the below XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:me="urn:netdocs:schemas:message" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="text()" />

   <xsl:template match="/">

      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <WANTED_DELIVERY_DATE>
            <xsl:value-of select="//order/additionalDate" />
      </WANTED_DELIVERY_DATE>

      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <CUSTOMER_PO_NO>
            <xsl:value-of select="//order/@documentNumber" />
      </CUSTOMER_PO_NO>

   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but it's only providing me two empty tags.

What might be the issue here ?

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not accounting for default namespaces (namespaces declared without a prefix).

`order` is in the namespace `urn:netdocs:schemas:document` (that's called a namespace uri).

`additionalDate` is in an empty namespace.

Try something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:msg="urn:netdocs:schemas:message"
  xmlns:doc="urn:netdocs:schemas:document"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msg doc">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/msg:message">
    <WANTED_DELIVERY_DATE>
      <xsl:value-of select="doc:order/additionalDate" />
    </WANTED_DELIVERY_DATE>
    <CUSTOMER_PO_NO>
      <xsl:value-of select="doc:order/@documentNumber" />
    </CUSTOMER_PO_NO>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notice that I bound the namespaces for `message` and `order` to prefixes (`msg` and `doc`). (You can use different prefixes, as long as the URI is the same.)

Also notice that no prefix was needed for `additionalDate` since it's in an empty namespace.

For more information on namespaces, take a look at:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/
- http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm

Comment: This was absolutely helpful. Thank you very much for explaining the things. Now I got it to working.